# How to hide and show a div on changing checkbox using angular?

Tags: angularjs

Using checkbox how to hide and show the span.
If checkbox is checked on the span should be dispaly, if uncheck it should not be display using angular

Here is a fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/d9uc1dxc/2/

```
   <div class="flw vreq2">
        <label>Voting require2</label>
        <div class="oneline">
       <div class="onoffswitches">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-
         checkbox"id="myonoffswitch7"/>
                <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch7">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                 </label>
         </div>
         <span class="teamsize">
         <label>Team Size</label><input type="text" />
         </span>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="val" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"/>
    <span ng-show="val">hello world</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-show or ng-hide in the span tag.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle example shows that you have not even bootstrapped AngularJs. Are you sure you selected a correct Tag? And you want to solve this issue in AngularJs?
If yes, the I would suggest you first go through the basics of AngularJs.
And here is an answer to your question.

**your html must look like**

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.7"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkBoxValue" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch7"/>
                <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch7">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                 </label>

         <div ng-hide="checkBoxValue">
         <span class="teamsize">
         <label>Team Size</label><input type="text" />
         </span>  
         </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Refer: http://plnkr.co/edit/sc2xRQCYOi22D9AYqCrX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I found the best answer

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-
       checkbox"id="myonoffswitch7" ng-model="checked" />

<span class="teamsize" ng-hide="checked">
  <label>Team Size</label><input type="text" />
</span>
```